# Deploy libs in hard-coded dir

Tags: directory-structure, libraries, deployment

I have a set of libraries and some apps that depend on it. Some of these libraries names might conflict with already installed libraries.

The easiest way for me to deploy them would be

- Install the libraries in a fixed-path "/usr/local/[my-firm]/lib"
- Compile my apps with a [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) pointing to this path
- My apps' installer can tell if the libraries are installed by looking at something like "/usr/local/[my-firm]/libversion"

What do you think about it ?

Is installing the libraries in a fixed path acceptable ?

**Edit**

I should add that I wish to be able to ship my libraries and my apps independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the libraries you install are specific for your application and may conflict with system libraries installed then I would recommend setting up a structure like this:

```
/opt/<app>/<version>/lib
```

or

```
/opt/<app-libs>/<version>/lib
```

This way you can deploy at will separately from others and not affect anything that someone else might require and you can force your application to look at those paths if you choose.